# Round and abs function in Idris

Tags: idris

I'm trying to write a function

```
roundedSqrt : Nat -> Nat
roundedSqrt = abs . round . sqrt . fromIntegral
```

Are there functions

```
round: Double -> Int
abs : Int -> Nat
```

or something analogous in Idris?

Edit:

```
floor : Double -> Int
ceiling : Double -> Int
```

would both be acceptable alternatives to `round` for my use-case.

Comment: Should `round x` return the nearest integer to `x`? (as in Haskell)

Comment: @AntonTrunov Ideally! Although floor or ceiling would also be acceptable for my use-case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to find out what you are asking is using the Idris REPL. Specifically the `:search` command (or its abbreviation `:s`).
To discover what we need in order to apply `sqrt` of type `Double -> Double` to a `Nat` we might try something like this:

```
Idris> :s Nat -> Double
< Prelude.Cast.cast : Cast from to => from -> to
Perform a cast operation.
```

Using the `cast` function that we could have written the following version:

```
roundedSqrtDoesntCompile : Nat -> Nat
roundedSqrtDoesntCompile = cast {to=Nat} . sqrt . cast {to=Double}
```

Unfortunately, it won't compile with the error:

> Can't cast from `Double` to `Nat`

because there is no `Cast Double Nat` instance in the standard library (so `cast {to=Nat}` is not legitimate).

As a workaround I propose to perform double (no pun intended) cast from `Double` to `Integer` to `Nat`:

```
roundedSqrt : Nat -> Nat
roundedSqrt = cast {to=Nat} . cast {to=Integer} . sqrt . cast {to=Double}
```

which can be written more concisely

```
roundedSqrt : Nat -> Nat
roundedSqrt = cast . cast {to=Integer} . sqrt . cast
```

`cast {to=Integer}` does [rounding towards zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer), a.k.a.  [truncation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation).

By the way, using `sqrt` might not be the best way of calculating this. Beware of the floating-point rounding errors, they can unexpectedly get you an off-by-one result. Since your function resembles the [integer square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root), it may be better to implement something close to that.

---

Now to the `abs`, `floor`, `ceiling`, and `round` functions.

The `Neg` interface defines `abs` with the following type:

```
abs : Neg ty => ty -> ty
```

So you will need to do some simple type casting to implement `abs : Int -> Nat`.

The standard Prelude also defines

```
floor : Double -> Double
ceiling : Double -> Double
```

So, again with a little work one can recast them into `Double -> Int`.

There is no standard `round` function, and if you still need it, then you could try implementing it using as an example the Haskell [`RealFrac`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#properFraction) typeclass.

Comment: `abs` has been moved from the `Neg`-interface to the `Abs`-interface in [#4196](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/pull/4196).